# Meteor how to serve multiple css for different media types?

Tags: css, meteor

I would like to have my Meteor app serve multiple css pages for various media types.  For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="handheld.css" />
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Also you can specify media types inside the css files.
Answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31281406/386213

Comment: Or you can specify media types inside the CSS file.
Detailed answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31281406/386213

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/packages/meteor/package.js
```

defined that `.css` files should be bundled.

However, taking a close look at [docs.meteor.com](http://docs.meteor.com), we can find this information:

> CSS files work just the same: the client will get a bundle with all the CSS in your tree (excluding the server and public subdirectories).

That last part is the interesting bit, if you place your CSS files in `/public` they will not get bundled together. Instead `app/lib/bundler.js` does the following around line 517:

```
files.cp_r(path.join(project_dir, 'public'),
           path.join(build_path, 'static'), {ignore: ignore_files});
```

And server side, any files that are unresolved will also be checked in `build/static`, which means that when you put `screen.css` in `/public` you can keep using `screen.css` on the client.