# How to specify a specific css file in METEOR

Tags: css, meteor

Meteor gathers up all the css into a single file and doesn't allow for a css to be specified for print media.

I would like to be able to specific a css file that should not be include in the bundle up of css AND I would like to include :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print-only.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

In the meteor page.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare CSS media types *inside* a CSS file. You don't need several different files for that.

For example, from http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp:

```
@media screen {
    p {
        font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
}

@media print {
    p {
        font-family: georgia, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a solution for us. We really do need the link ability. Use of the link element and the @media tag are not equivalent.